# Object variable not set error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm an average VBA user and can't figure out why I'm getting an error.

Here is the code:

```
    Set cell = AA.Sheets(sc).Columns("E").Find(Name, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not cell Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddress = cell.Address
    Do
        s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(AA.Sheets(av).Rows(3).Find(AA.Sheets(sc).Range("F" & cell.Row)), AA.Sheets(av).Range("A3:NC3"), 0)
        p = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(AA.Sheets(av).Rows(3).Find(AA.Sheets(sc).Range("G" & cell.Row)), AA.Sheets(av).Range("A3:NC3"), 0)
        Set cell = AA.Sheets(sc).Columns("E").FindNext(cell)
    Loop While cell.Address <> FirstAddress 'ERROR ON THIS LINE
End If
Set cell = Nothing
```

I am getting an object variable or With block variable not set error. after the first run trough, 'cell' is returning 'Nothing' even though there should be 2 more passes. If I remove the 's =' and 'p =' lines, it finishes correctly. I need those for what I'm doing though.

How would I go about fixing this? Thanks!

Comment: The error means that the FindNext method on previous line did not find any matching cell. It's hard to help you more without seeing the surrounding code and without explanation on sheet contents

Comment: This is the only code that is relevant to the error though. Nothing before will really make a difference. Like I said in the OP, if I were to remove the two lines before the error and step the code, it finds all three instances. It's when I try to get 'p' and 's' it errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because the 's' and 'p' line use the 'Find' object of Excel. There is only one instance of 'Find' for the application. You initialize it on the 1st line, and then use "FindNext". That works only if you do not use the "Find" object in-between.

Comment: ok... that makes sense. I'll see if I can tweak the code without using the Find function. Thanks!

Comment: can't upvote (not enough rep)... I just used a loop instead and it's working like a charm! :)